# Display fast changing values in the browser

Tags: java, html, browser

I have written a Java program, which reads numbers from different files. The numbers are added while being read from the files and the sum is displayed in a browser. The browser keeps on displaying the new sum getting created at every step.

I know how to display static values in a browser. I can use Javascripts. But I don't know what mechanism to use to display continuously a changing value.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to request the data to display from the server.  You can use a data-binding library like Knockout to automatically update the page as the underlying model changes, or you can just use a library like jquery to modify the DOM on your own.

Alternatively, you could keep a pipe open to the server using the Comet model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29.  However, it can be expensive to eat up a thread for long periods of time on your web server.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Check out knockout.js http://www.knockoutjs.com/ it is a framework for updating UI automatically when data changes